# Help finding Buck/Boost Regulator IC

Tags: batteries, voltage-regulator, integrated-circuit, component-selection

I have been trying to find a suitable Buck/Boost IC with certain features, but having gone through multiple Manufacturer's product tables, I can't find one that meets my needs. I think this is more because the terms arn't always shared between Manufacturers (Like some call them regulators, others converters, other controllers).

Target would be a small circuit that allows between battery and wall power supply voltages, to an adjustable/selectable output, for a portable microcontroller. It should regulate the entire VIN, from buck to boost, without issues.

Features needed (Doesn't have to be exactly this, but close to it):

- 1.0V to 6.0V input. (From a single NiMH 1.2V to 4 Alkaline 1.5V)
- Adjustable out (minimum 3.3v AND 5.0V selectable.)
- 500mA (300mA minimum)
- Minimal Components needed (no inductor, no big caps, no external switch)
- Under Voltage protection (Do NiMH need undervoltage protection?)
- SOIC or SOT or SOP preferred

I've seen some that are inductor-less, internal switch, small caps, but only provide 140mA from 2V to 5.5V (MCP1253). I've seen some that can take up to 12V in and 2A, but require an inductor, bigger caps, and is a Leadless package (DFN) (TPS63060). Being inductor-less is not a deal breaker, but as I understand, the higher the current capacity, the bigger an inductor needs to be.

It be nice to get single cell input range, but I understand if it can't be found. Anything close to this requirements would help.

Comment: Any switching regulator is going to have an inductor, especially at those current levels. If you don't want to deal with it, you're going to have to confine your search to complete DC-DC converter modules, not bare chips.

Comment: @DaveTweed I am seeing that. Like I said, it doesn't have to be exact, needing an inductor isn't the issue, its only if it needs a big one. And the reason I would like an IC is because I want to integrate it into a board.

Answer (score 2):

I had a quick look on Linear technology and it didn't come up with anything: -
[image]

But, don't despair... [Here](http://parametric.linear.com/html/Internal_Power_Switch_Buck-Boost?undefined&c[1646][]=Buck-Boost&c[1646][]=SEPIC&c[1032][]=*||1&c[1033][]=6||*&c[1105][]=*||3.3&c[1034][]=3.3||*&c[1035][]=1.94||11.6&c[1107][]=0.3||1.8&vinmin=1&vinmax=6&vout=3.3&iout=0.3&qs=1) is the link and you can try entering your own parameters and tweaking where necessary. Personally speaking i think the 1V to 6V range is likely to be the biggest problem but give it a go.

Linear technology is my personal favourite for this type of device but you can also try the other suspects like TI, Maxim, AD etc..